# how can i create a auto updating time field in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime

I have created a post table. I want to have a time field in the table which will auto update in self with the time. Like say if the post is inserted in a row at 1pm and I am checking it after 2hrs it should contain the value 2 or something like that.

At the time of inserting the post it will contain 0 minutes.
After 30 minutes if i execute a select query it should contain 30

Is there a way to do that in mysql only?

Comment: what abaut save the creation time on database and just do on select `now()-row_time` ?

Comment: thanks mate but in mysql is there a way like the same i have asked?
thanks in advance

Comment: maybe but if its can be done the way u asked, think abaut the cost of update all rows of the table every minute. i still think you shuld do : `select now()-row_time from your_table;`

Comment: the problem is i want to save the time for a particular time zone i dont know how to change the time zone in mysql

Comment: [googleit](http://bit.ly/LA3kPa)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey first you just save your time time in table on inserting time with NOW() sql function and when you run the select query just subtract table insert time from NOW(). it will work.

```
select NOW() - inserttiontime from table;
```

Comment: the problem is i want to save the time for a particular time zone i dont know how to change the time zone in mysql

Comment: For timezone change Use CONVERT_TZ() like SELECT CONVERT_TZ(now(),'US/Eastern','US/Central').

Comment: i have voted your answer up...please vote my question up